# what is the best way to connect to database in c#?

Tags: c#, database, linq, ado.net, entity

I'm a beginner in c# and i'm looking for the best way to connect to and work with sql server in c#. i found there are three ways to work with databases:

1. ADO.NET
2. Linq
3. Entity Framework

but i become confused as to which one is more useful and applied.
please help me?
thanks

Answer (score 7):

> I'm looking for best way to connect to and work with sql server in c#

'best way' can be treated differently depending on your project requirements. There is no best way for all cases. Some times you need ease of development, some times you need best performance, some times you need compromise of both (then I pick [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)). Also it depends on complexity of your application - whether you have rich domain model, or you simply display table data on UI.

> 1.ADO.NET

Fastest way, but requires lot of manual coding. You should manually setup database connections, open and close them, create commands, provide parameters to commands and execute commands. Mapping of query results also should be done manually.

> 2.Linq

It's not way to connect to database. Linq is language integrated queries, which have many implementations - Linq to Xml, Linq to DataSet, Linq to Object, Linq to SQL, Linq to Entities etc.

> 3.Entity Framework

Entity Framework uses Linq to Entities and it is built on ADO.NET (internally Linq queries are are translated to ADO.NET code). It is easy to use, because EF handles connections, generate and execute commands, and map query results to entities for you. But you should pay with performance for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is only ONE way to connect to a database . ADO.NET, more specifig: the Connection object.

Now, LINQ, ENtity Framework - guess what, they do not talk to the database. They use ADO.NET to do that.

They are all about easier programming in the application - talking to the database is done by the same underlying classes. Everything goes through a Connection, a Command and a SqlReader if data is returned.

That said, definitely learn Entity Framework - an ORM is baseline and writing handcrafted SL should be left to those instances it makes sense. Very complex queries that can not be expressed in an ORM form. And learn proper SQL - databases can do a LOT more than most people are aware of.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "best way", because there are many advantages and disadvantages to each one of them, so it depends.

For example, entity framework is heavy, but convenient way to connect to database. It generates objects from your tables and views automatically.

LINQ is less heavy, but some people find it less convenient.